# Password-change email has a broken link

Tags: bug, login, openid, email, password

I changed my Stack Exchange password today and received a confirmation email with a link to "your Stack Exchange account" (https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) that, if you're not logged in, returns a "Not Found" page.  The page is found if logged in, but should otherwise indicate that you need to log in to see it.

Comment: Noticed it for the first time ( ^_^) `<span style="color:maroon" title="Because we care">&lt;3</span>`